# Assigning React JSX to a variable

Tags: reactjs

I was wondering if anyone can explain this syntax to me. In react, when assigning jsx to a variable such as:

```
const example = (
  jsx
);
```

Why are the parenthesis used? I understand that with arrow functions you can omit the function body braces and omit the return keyword. But why are the parenthesis used here?

Comment: Its not needed, although some people believe it to look nicer.

Comment: It used to be used to group one more lines of JSX code and prevent Javascript Engine of automatically insert a semicolon at the end of the first line of code. But currently, as far as I know, it doesn't happen anymore.

Comment: Depending on your compiler and stuff it used to be necessary. I think most are smart enough these days. Parenthesis are used for literal shorthand and stuff as well. [Good read explaining in more detail](https://medium.com/@leannezhang/curly-braces-versus-parenthesis-in-reactjs-4d3ffd33128f)